# Must I rebuild Nunit 2.6.2 to use it with .net 4.0?

Tags: nunit, nunit-2.6

When I try to run some tests with:

nunit-console.exe <mydll> /framework:net-4.0

I am rewarded with:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'nunit-console-runner, Version=2.6.2.12296,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToke n=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'nunit-console-runner, Version=2.6.2.12296, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77'    at
>   NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Class1.Main(String[] args)

There is no file named nunit-console-runner anywhere.

When I leave off the /framework, all is well. However, I need the /framework as my goal is to debug as mixed-mode test failure on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?